# Dynamic PVC/storage class encryption in GCP

Tags: storage, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, disk-encryption, disk-volume

I'm trying to create PVC which has the storage class encrypted. These PVCs are created dynamically.
As per this link- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#gce-pd
for AWS EBS, there is a parameter 'encrypted' which can be set to true or false to enable the encryption for the disk/volume.
Example below for AWS:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: ebs
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  zone: "###ZONE###"
  encrypted: "true"
```

However, there is no such parameter for GCE PD in GCP.
Is there any way in which I can provide the encryption parameter for the GCE PD so that the resulting disk is encrypted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the [Encrypt disks with customer-supplied encryption keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/customer-supplied-encryption):

> By default, Compute Engine encrypts all data at rest. Compute Engine
>   handles and manages this encryption for you without any additional
>   actions on your part. However, if you wanted to control and manage
>   this encryption yourself, you can provide your own encryption keys.
>
> If you provide your own encryption keys, Compute Engine uses your key
>   to protect the Google-generated keys used to encrypt and decrypt your
>   data. Only users who can provide the correct key can use resources
>   protected by a customer-supplied encryption key.
>
> Google does not store your keys on its servers and cannot access your
>   protected data unless you provide the key. This also means that if you
>   forget or lose your key, there is no way for Google to recover the key
>   or to recover any data encrypted with the lost key.
>
> When you delete a persistent disk, Google discards the cipher keys,
>   rendering the data irretrievable. This process is irreversible.

Type of issued storage depends on options you will specify:

- In case `replication-type` is set to `regional-pd` - you will have [Regional persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#repds)
- In case `replication-type` is set to `none` - you will have [https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#pdspecs)

[Storage options](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/) will help you ensure the `Zonal standard persistent disks` and `Regional persistent disks` have:

> -Encryption at rest: yes
>
> -Custom encryption keys: yes

Follow the [Encrypt disks with customer-supplied encryption keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/customer-supplied-encryption) procedure to  encrypt **new persistent disks with your own key. You cannot encrypt existing persistent disks with your own key.**

Please pay attention to restrictions:

Compute Engine does not store encryption keys with [instance templates](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/), so you cannot use your own keys to encrypt disks in a [managed instance group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/).

Hope this help you understand this topic